# Self Hosted Gitlab-ce cannot filter/search some of the issues

Tags: filtering, gitlab-ce

I have transferred my company gitlab to self hosted gitlab by direct transfer. I knew it was not ready from production use but we preferred to use it.
My problem is that gitlab could not filter some issues even they exists in the issue list.

I am thinking a database reindexing is going to solve the issue but I am not sure if it's related with the db indexes.

Comment: As I guessed database re-indexing did not fix the issue. Unfortunately, I could not find any reason for this phenomenon or any similar issue in the internet.